# Collect Flows in Service

Tags: android, service, kotlin-coroutines, foreground-service, kotlin-flow

So, I'm trying to collect data from flows in my Foreground service (LifecycleService) in onCreate(), but after the first callback, it is not giving new data.

The code is :

```
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                observeCoinsPrices()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use `lifecycleScope.launch` instead of `lifecycleScope. launchWhenStarted` since we are already passing `STARTED` state inside `repeatOnLifecycle`

Comment: I tried that, but same issue

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get `lifecycleScope.launch` to work in the `LifecycleService.onCreate` method without it freezing the app, so what I did instead was moved the collector into a method that I use to start the service, assign the Job into a property so I can cancel it when the Service is destroyed.

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.Job
//...

class MyService : LifecycleService() {
 //...
 private lateinit var myJob: Job

   // my custom method for starting The Foreground service
   fun startTheService() {
      // call startForeground()
      
      //...

      myJob = lifecycleScope.launch {
          collectFromFlow()
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
       myJob.cancel()
    }
}
```

In my case, I was wanting to update text in the foreground notification every time a value was emitted to my Flow collector.

Comment: Services run in the main thread and lifecycleScope launches coroutines in the main thread as well. Did you try switching context by changing the dispatcher to io or default?

Answer (score 0):

Because Flow used in `observeCoinsPrices()` not replay the latest value (replay < 1). You should change Flow logic

Comment: I'm collecting the same flow in fragment, it is working fine there.